# PHP file_exists, filemtime, stack, not work, but file exits,

Tags: php, file-exists, filemtime

I need to read some paths from a csv file and show it in the browser.

I can read the file with

```
file_get_contents.
```

But the encoding from the csv file is wrong.
So i need to use

```
mb_convert_encoding($array[$i], 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');
```

to get the correct path.

After this, i display the filename and the path with a  tag

```
echo "<a href='" . $encoded_path . "'>" . $only_filname ."</a>";
```

When i click on the link, the file will be open. It works great!

At the end i need to show the last modified date. Here is my problem
I wrote

```
echo "Content last changed: ".date("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($encoded_path));
```

i got the wrong date.... Each date was "1970"

what can be wrong?

I tried to use a other function

```
stat() -> mtime
```

it didn't work.
that was the reason, why i would like to check if the file exists...

I tried this with
`if (file_exists())`

so i saw, that the file ist not founded

i try to change the path, to a absolute path ->not help

my path look like this

from the csv file, i got this:

```
$path = "files/directory1/my file.pdf";
```

i tried to use

```
$newpath =  "../../files/directory1/my file.pdf" // not work
$newpath =  "c:/xampp/htdocs/web/files/directory1/my file.pdf" // not work
$newpath =  __DIR__ . $path; //not work
$newpath =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $path; //not work
```

the path works,  if i copy the output of each version and paste it into the windows explorer
the path works in a  tag too.

if i show the path, select it with the mouse and copy paste it to the file_exists function it works too
`$newpath =  "../../files/directory1/my file.pdf"; echo $newpath;`

`if(file_exist("../../files/directory1/my file.pdf")) // works`

only file_exists and the other filetime functions not work

Thank you

Comment: have you tried and absolute path from root? eg $path = "/path/to/your/file.txt"; with relative paths you need to know the working directory your script is using if unsure you can do that with echoing getcwd();

Comment: This is all over the place. So, are you having a problem with `filemtime` not returning the correct time, or are you having a problem dynamically creating the file path that is being sent to `filemtime`?

Comment: `filemtime()` returns `FALSE` when it gets an error. This will be treated as `0` by `date()`, and that's 1970-01-01. You need to check whether it returns a valid date before trying to print it.

Comment: yes. i think it returns the false date, because the file will be NOT find.
The question is: why the file does not find, when i use the path with the variable, but when i copy the output from the variable, in the file_exists function, it works.

is it possible, that the encoding of the string(path) inside the variable is not compatible, with the file_exists function.

Comment: What is the _actual_ filename? Does it have any non-english characters in it? There can be different codepoint representations for identical _looking_ strings that would cause this type of behaviour, and which one is actually used by the filesystem can depend on a number of factors, even being altered by the OS or filesystem driver when the file is created. The solution being to use [Normalizer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer) to convert the filename to the form expected by the FS.

Comment: no, there are only englih characters
like: ../../files/betriebsrat/Dienstrechtliches/Famil 30.pdf

Comment: Given that it's German I would suggest hexdumping the string and double-checking. The source encoding being UTF16 also usually implies that there are going to be a lot of higher-order codepoints stuffed in there somewhere.

Comment: good idea.... i tried bin2hex and return it via hex2bin and got between each letter two black "?" marks..

Comment: _Two_ mystery marks? That's weird. Can you `bin2hex()` an example line from the original CSV file and add that to the question?

Comment: i tried it, but after i press commit, it will delete the marks
i tried iconv... but i got this message  Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input

Comment: Okay I find the mistake. I tried a lot of things. One idea was to split the string and check each letter.. I found on each path a white space on the end. But it was not interpreted as a space. When I tried to str_replace the spaces, it didn't detect this whitespace. I don't know what it is. When I check it with a if " ", at doesn't detect the white space... the encoding was utf-16LE.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Non-breaking space

There is a character in UTF-8 and UTF-16 which looks identical the space character, but is actually a completely different character altogether:
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00A0

The non-breaking space character is visually indistinguishable from a space character, but will *not* be converted when you try to use str_replace to replace all spaces, because it has a different code point.

The non-breaking space comes up mainly in situations like yours, when you're copying data from a sophisticated source, like a whitespace-safe CSV file, or a website that uses `&nbsp;` spaces.

Here's an explanation of the character, and why it's useful:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

## How to prevent the issue in the future

Right after you've fixed up the character encoding, add a line like this:

```
$encoded_path = str_replace("\u{a0}", ' ', $encoded_path);
```

This will convert all non-breaking spaces to a *regular* spaces.

Or, if you'd just like to remove that one trailing space and be done with it, you can do that directly with the trim function:

```
$encoded_path = trim($encoded_path, " \u{a0}");
```

Comment: really good tip. know i found with bin2hex,  what character gives the problem: 0d0a
so i can remove it correctly...

But today i found a other problem with encoding, because the "-" will not display correctly

i wrote in my last posts, that i found the coding from the original file, which includes the paths. It is UTF-16 . so i use mb_convert to convert UTF-16 to UTF-8. But the "-" will be conding to ` †`

Comment: please follow the link to the image. i can't paste it here 
 [https://ibb.co/YQPfrZq](https://ibb.co/YQPfrZq)

Comment: do it now with this script
`function unklare_codings_entfernen($string){
  //string in hex code
  $string = bin2hex($string);
  //unklares zeichen als hex code suchen und mit tatsächlichem zeichen (hexcode davon) ersetzen
  $string = str_replace("13e280a0", "e2809320" , $string);
  $string = hex2bin($string);
  return $string;
}`